# How to replace all * characters in a string using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to delete `*` characters if it is present in a string.

This is my code but it's not working.

```
String.replace(/*/g '')
```

Comment: `.replace(/\*/g, '')`

Comment: `stringvar.split('*').join('')`

Answer (score 5):

You have to escape the special character `*` with a backslash, as it has another meaning in a regex.

```
String.replace(/\*/g, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"Your string".replace("*", "");
```

Comment: This will only replace the first asterisk